# Upload a servlet page on a server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, spring-mvc

i create a web site with java, spring framework,apache tomcat 7 and NetBeans.The last days i try to upload on a server but i have problems. I talk with the admin of the server and he said me,the form of the uploaded server seems not to be correct.
I'm using svn(assembla) and i store there my project.Then from there i send it to the main server i want to run it.The project when it is in the assembla(and in the main server i want to run it) contains the following files:

1. nbproject
2. src (contains the conf,myproject(with all the .java files))
3. web (contains: META-INF,WEB-INF,index.jsp)

and the folowing xml files: build,catalog,My-build and these files:command-To-Deploy.txt,My-build.properties

Moreover.My start page is a login page.At the index page i have only this line of code:

```
<c:redirect url="/log"/>
```

log is the URI i want to redirect the page.He told me that there is no log.jsp(the jsp for the log i named it as mainLogin.jsp). I'm not sure but i think that this is not a problem.

Does anyone who uploads before servlet knows what should i do and what files should i upload?

Answer (score 1):

If you just uploaded java files to a server, they won't do much good.  You need to compile them, preferable packaged into a jar, for the jsp to call them.

Also, unless you're using libraries/javascript to change it, the url path operates explicitly like a file path.  www.mysite.com/folder/file.jsp will look in /folder/ for the file name file.jsp to serve.  So the url 'log' has no way of magically knowing that you want it to access mainLogin.jsp.

Comment: I'm using: @RequestMapping(value = "/log", method = RequestMethod.GET) up from a Controller method in order to catch the URI.So thats the reason i said that this probably is not a problem.I'm i right or not?

Comment: Looks reasonable, but you still need to compile your .java files into .class files in order for tomcat to use them.

Comment: I think that the best way is to make a .war file